# Spring MVC 4.3.2+AJAX+JSON Error 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: ajax, spring

First of all I've to say that I have read a lot of similar answers to this problems, none of them solved the issue. So I can only ask with my own code.

The problem comes with a Spring MVC webapp and AJAX call w/ JSON request/response and error is common "406 Not Acceptable"

Here is the important part of the code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/search")
public class AjaxController {

@Autowired
private UserManager userManager;
@RequestMapping(value = "getUserData.htm")
    public Login getSearchResultViaAjax(@RequestBody SearchCriteriaUserId search) {
        Login login = new Login();
        login.setUsername("john");
        login.setPassword("1234");
        return login;
    }
}
```

The JS code

```
function searchViaAjax() {
var data = {}
data["uId"] = $("#uId").val();

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    contentType : "application/json",
    url : "search/getUserData.htm",
    data : JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType : 'json',
    timeout : 100000,
    success : function(data) {
        console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
        $("#message").html(data);
    },
    error : function(e) {
        console.log("ERROR: ", e);
        $("#message").html(e.responseText);
    },
    done : function(e) {
        console.log("DONE");
    }
});
}
```

AJAX makes correctly the call (it passes the argument of THE #uId to the Controller). 
I've checked the following tips that i've found, with no success:
1) "mvc:annotation-driven" in dispatcher-servlet.xml
2) Jackson dependencies in POM
3) Tried the @ResponseBody (without @RestController) and "produces='application/json'"
4) Headers headers="Accept=..." 
5) Checked gettes/setters on POJO returned class

I don't know where else to look at.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after 48hrs of fight error came out by either one of these 2 things (really don't know which):
1) I was using "*.htm" url-pattern on web.xml to redirect to Dispatcher Servlet. Changed it to "*.do".
2) Downgrade Spring version 4.3.2 --> 4.2.2

Thanks all.